# UIView presented with Black screen, fix?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I call a View to be presented with the following code:

```
#import "infoView.h"
...
infoView *viewInfo = [[infoView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewInfo.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:viewInfo animated:YES];
```

But when it is presented in run-time the view that is loaded turns out black.
Currently I am using storyboard, but I need to use this code, for it is a lot more efficient in my case, because I am dealing with multiple views!

It works fine if I connect it via StoryBoard.

I should be seeing 2 labels, 1 UITextView, and 2 UIButton.

The view was created using StoryBoard, when the .m and .h files for the view where created I did not add a .xib for it. And also it is linked through the "Custom Class" section in StoryBoard.

Thanks, hope someone can help!

Comment: You haven't told us what you expected to see instead of black. And you should give us more of an idea of how the infoView class is written.

Comment: Also, please name classes starting with a capital letter. 'infoView' looks like a variable/property rather than a class.

Comment: @SirKaydian nice thing to "mock" the people who are trying to help you, nice...

Comment: @SirKaydian yes, the capital letter actually does matter

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally pretty bad form to mock people who are taking the time and effort to help you.

Naming is important it makes your code easier to work with and allows other people to use it. Not following the conventions for the language you are working in is dangerous and means that your code is not compatible with other developers as things are interpreted differently.

If you look at the docuemntation for [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll see this note in the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method description

> If your app uses a storyboard to define a view controller and its associated views, your app never initializes objects of that class directly. Instead, view controllers are either instantiated by the storyboard—either automatically by iOS when a segue is triggered or programmatically when your app calls the storyboard object’s instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method. When instantiating a view controller from a storyboard, iOS initializes the new view controller by calling its initWithCoder: method instead. iOS automatically sets the nibName property to a nib file stored inside the storyboard.

Therefore you are instantiating your controller wrong, the storyboard should be instantiating it. Which is done like this (naming corrected)

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]];
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InfoViewController"];
infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self infoViewController animated:YES];
```

### Side note

`infoView` is a bad name for the class not only because you didn't start with a capital but also because it's completely deceiving. Anyone reading this would assume that `InfoView` is a subclass of `UIView` not `UIViewController`.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the tips and tricks! My bad if I came off a little strong. I do now see how there should be a standard naming system. I am fairly new to coding in general (about 3 months) and would like to make everything the best I can. So once again thanks for the help, and advice!